# How to set animation when I click on button at that time move image from left to right and right to left in android?

Tags: android

I wanna translate 2 images image When I click on Button, At that time from left image move left to right and right image move right to left(both image come in center at that time stop animation) on emulator using android animation.I'm new to android animation.How could i do that.?
coding is much appreciated.Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

i can't explain everything here but i help you to do that. first you must create two new XML file (Animation in old versions or Tween Animation in new versions) for each image , then use translate. for example:

```
<translate android:fromXDelta="10"
    android:toXDelta="100"
    android:duration="2000"    
    />
```

for left image, and for right one use your numbers.
then in java file, set your Button and images. then define animation and use them. i think this example is comprehensible:

```
    final ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(main.this, R.anim.animation);
            iv1.startAnimation(anim);
            iv2.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    });
```

in this example, i use one animation for both of them.
and remember in this site, you can get help from other, not absolute code.

Comment: if this is your answer, you must accept it. it's a reason for us to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

add two xml files to `res/anim` folder of your project like below:

`lefttoright.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-600%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="300"
    android:zAdjustment="bottom">
</translate>
```

`righttoleft.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="400%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="300"
    android:zAdjustment="bottom">
</translate>
```

In your layout file keep one `ImageView` at the left of the screen and other one at the right of the screen

Use the following code snippet in your button's onClick event:

```
lefttoright = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            R.anim.lefttoright);
    righttoleft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            R.anim.righttoleft);
imageView1.startAnimation(lefttoright);
imageView2.startAnimation(righttoleft);
```

then implement your animation listener:

```
lefttoright.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //update imageView's position (e.g. center)
                    }
                });
```

Do same thing for `righttoleft`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: lefttoright = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.lefttoright); what is lefttoright over here

Comment: Sorry forgot to define type! `lefttoright` is an `Animation` type variable.